# Phase Kickback - factoring Dirac representation

Tags: qiskit, textbook-and-exercises

In section 2.3 of the Qiskit textbook (Phase Kickback), there's an example where a controlled-T gate is applied to $|1+\rangle$.

You're asked to attempt the same thing with $|0+\rangle$.  I've done this by means of statevectors and successfully got the correct answer (that it has no effect):
$$\text{Controlled-T}|0+\rangle$$
$$=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}
\end{pmatrix}\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\\\end{pmatrix}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\\\end{pmatrix}$$

The textbook's example (using $|1+\rangle$) performs the calculation in Dirac representation - i.e. by factoring out the individual qubits.  I decided to try the same thing with the above.  Here's what I got:
$$|0+\rangle = |0\rangle \otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |01\rangle)$$

$$\text{Controlled-T}|0+\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}|01\rangle)$$
$$=|0\rangle \otimes\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}|1\rangle)$$
When I then multiply that out to get the statevector, I get:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}\begin{pmatrix}1\\e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\\0\\0\\\end{pmatrix}$$
which is clearly different.
What am I doing wrong with the algebraic approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textrm{Controlled-T} = |0\rangle\langle 0| \otimes I + |1\rangle\langle1| \otimes T$

Thus, if you apply this to the state $|\psi \rangle = |0\rangle \bigg( \dfrac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg)$ you have:

\begin{align}
\textrm{Controlled-T} |\psi\rangle &= \bigg[|0\rangle\langle 0| \otimes I + |1\rangle\langle1| \otimes T \bigg] |0\rangle \bigg( \dfrac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg) \\
&= \bigg[ |0\rangle\langle 0| \otimes I \bigg]|0\rangle \bigg( \dfrac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg)  + \bigg[  |1\rangle\langle1| \otimes T \bigg]|0\rangle  \bigg( \dfrac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg)  \\
&=   |0\rangle \bigg( \dfrac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg) + 0 = |\psi\rangle
\end{align}

Thus nothing changed.

Comment: Could you maybe explain why the second term becomes $0$ ? I am definitely missing something here !

Comment: $(|1\rangle \langle 1|)|0\rangle = \vec{0} $.  I should have wrote my $0$  with a vector notation earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Controlled-T gate has no effect on the $|01\rangle$ state (the control qubit is in $|0\rangle$ state), rather than add a phase to it.

Comment: While I understand that in principle, it doesn't seem to work with the example in the textbook. They factored out Controlled-T|1+⟩. The steps they used were as follows:
$$|1+\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|10\rangle+|11\rangle$$
$$Controlled-T|1+\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|10\rangle+e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}|11\rangle)$$
$$=|1\rangle\otimes\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}|1\rangle)$$

This only makes sense to me if the textbook is using the second qubit as the control, so I was following that pattern. What did I miss?

Comment: The first qubit is actually the control; the |10⟩ term didn't change because T gate has no effect on the |0⟩ state, so it's applied in the controlled variant but doesn't have effect.

Comment: Right - thank you.  This makes a *lot* more sense now.  I'd normally seen the first qubit as the control, but I couldn't understand why the T gate had just been dropped from the $|10\rangle$ state.  Upvoted.